# ¿Cómo puedo elegir que archivo de configuración utilizar en mi aplicación c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, app.config

En mi proyecto de C#, tengo una aplicación de consola que se configura a través de un App.config en el cual guardo unas IPs de unas máquinas. Ahora quiero configurar otros entornos con IPs (App1.config, App2.config...) y me gustaría que mi aplicación me permitiese elegir que archivo .config leer según en que entorno quiero trabajar. He leído acerca de mapear mis archivos .config pero no entiendo cómo hacerlo.[image: Mi proyecto]

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas varios .config, necesitas varias keys, suponiendo que dispones de algo similar a esto:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="IPUno" value="127.0.0.1" />   
</appSettings>
```

Que puedes recuperar en el código como:

```
string IPuno = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPUno"].ToString();
```

puedes añadir mas keys e invocar a varias.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="IPUno" value="127.0.0.1" />   
    <add key="IPDos" value="192.168.1.1" />   
</appSettings>

string IPuno = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPUno"].ToString();
string IPdos = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPDos"].ToString();
```

Según la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-add-multiple-sets-of-settings-to-your-application-in-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), la manera ideal de  realizarlo es usando un archivo settings y a la hora de arrancar la app manejar que configuración deseas.

Puedes crear uno pulsando click derecho en Propiedades/Properties:

> Agregar/Add -> Nuevo Elemento/New Element -> Archivo de configuración/ configuration file

Ahí puedes crear varios e ir invocando los deseados, por ejemplo:

```
var configUno = Properties.Settings.NombreConfigUno;
var configDos = Properties.Settings.NombreConfigDos;
```

Comment: Tengo que gestionar varios entornos que tienen bastantes keys, por eso quiero organizarlos en distintos archivos .config, para que sea más sencillo elegir el entono con un mismo código.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, el config no es lo ideal para eso, la mejor manera es usando un archivo [`settings`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-add-multiple-sets-of-settings-to-your-application-in-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)